# Sending terms instead of iolists to an Erlang driver

Tags: erlang, erlang-driver

Is there an equivalent of [`driver_output_term`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_driver.html#driver_output_term) in the other direction, i.e. sending an Erlang term to the driver without converting it to an iolist first? If not, I presumably should convert my term using `term_to_binary` and parse it on the C side with `ei`; any good examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, you can only send stuff that's in `iodata()` format.

If all you want send to the driver is integers and strings, it might be more efficient (and a lot easier) to use your own term-to-iodata encoding, as in [this tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) from the Erlang documentation. They use a function to convert their calls to a mapping that can be sent to the driver directly and therefore doesn't need to be encoded using `term_to_binary()`.

```
encode({foo, X}) -> [1, X];
encode({bar, Y}) -> [2, Y].
```

This mapping is feasible if `X` and `Y` are assumed to be small integers.
On the C side, the first byte of the input buffer is switched upon to call the appropriate function using the second byte as the argument:

```
static void example_drv_output(ErlDrvData handle, char *buff, int bufflen)
{
    example_data* d = (example_data*)handle;
    char fn = buff[0], arg = buff[1], res;
    if (fn == 1) {
        res = foo(arg);
    } else if (fn == 2) {
        res = bar(arg);
    }
    driver_output(d->port, &res, 1);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my terms are complex enough that using `ei` is easier.